# Get specific tweet data from twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, telegram, tweepy

I am trying to find the number of likes, comments, reposts, and bookmarks of a specific tweet based on the tweet URL. Is there any way to find all these numbers using the Twitter API? Currently, I am using the following code, but it's giving me an error:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, secret_key, access_token,access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweet = api.get_status("1765403157746639282")
print(tweet)
```

Error:

> 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2
> endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If
> you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access
> level. You can learn more here:
> https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

Comment: Do you have a paid account?

Comment: Contact Twitter directly about increasing your access level, there's nothing we can do for you here.

Comment: @JonSG Yes I have Basic Paid Account.

Comment: `tweepy.API()` calls the v1.1 API and we should call V2, so change to `tweepy.Client()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am leaving solution here. I used twitter v2 api

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/metrics